# How to force AD resync on ProxMox firewall version 5.2.1?

Tags: active-directory, proxmox

Does someone know how to force Active Directory resync on ProxMox firewall version 5.2.1 since the "pveum realm sync" command is not available yet on this outdated version?

pve-manager/5.2-1/0fcd7879 (running kernel: 4.15.17-1-pve)

Thanks in advance for the help & support !

BR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading between the lines in [the manual](https://pve.proxmox.com/pve-docs/pveum.1.html) section as to what `pveum realm sync <realm>` does:

> ### Synching LDAP-Based Realms
>
> *It’s possible to automatically sync users and groups for LDAP-based realms (LDAP & Microsoft Active Directory), rather than having to add them to Proxmox VE manually ...*

the absence of a `realm sync` option implies  you have to manually add and/or remove each user and group that is modified in AD...

---

Probably redundant: but most people use their firewalls for perimeter security and not keeping your security appliances up to date almost completely invalidates their purpose.

Comment: Ok yes, after creating the entry for each users, the passwords were automatically (re)synchronize. I totally agree with you regarding the security purpose of such outdated firewalls in the end.  it's a situation I simply inherited as I'm a new employee in this firm ;-)